# Login loop in Azure portal - "Microsoft has enabled security defaults to keep your account secure

Tags: azure-active-directory, azureportal

A user in our tenant is facing login loop while trying to login to https://portal.azure.com.

[image]

While reading through some documents on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-security-defaults , found that security defaults should be turned off in our tenant, which is weird because it was already off.

[image]

Steps performed already:

1. MFA for the account was removed and set to Microsoft Authenticator app again.
2. SMS MFA removed and added again
3. Security Defaults turned off
4. Tried to access on Incognito mode / In private session in Edge.

Still, the same issue, none of the above seems to have resolved the issue.

Can someone please guide me through this to solve this. Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

Make sure to have **Global Administrator role** and disable the security defaults like below:

[image]

**When I tried to sign-in as a user, I still got the same screen as below:**

[image]

When I tried to login after **few minutes**, I dint get the above screen and logged in to the Portal successfully:

[image]

Please **note** that, enabling/disabling security defaults takes few minutes to reflect and doesn't work instantly.

Comment: The question is not programming-related and shouldn't be answered here (since it will be eventually closed). Just close-vote (as not programming related). It belongs on ServerFault (or as documentation request)

Comment: @DavidMakogon thanks for the heads up, will close the question and post it on ServerFault.